# Direct Integration with function as upper bound

Tags: calculus

I'm studying for a final and trying to figure out how to solve this problem below (using the First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus)

$$\int_{1}^{e^{x}} \ln (t)\, dt$$

I tried subsitution where $u = e^{x}$ but then I got stuck at

$$\int_{1}^{u} \ln (t)\, dt$$

I can't figure out the next step, would anyone be able to help?

Comment: Try substituting $t = e^u$ instead.

Comment: Are you just asking what the anti-derivative of $ln(t)$ is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: instead of substituting $e^x$, substitute $t$. Then integrate by parts.

Comment: I had to stare at the problem to figure out what you were trying to get at (with substituting t instead of e^x) but I figured it out! Thanks a lot, it seemed really trivial once I noticed what to do.

Comment: @TaiM.: remember that after the substitution you get $\int_0^x ue^u\,du$, not $\int_0^x u\, du$ (since if $t=e^u$, $dt=e^u du$).

Answer (score 1):

Well, $\int \log(x) = x\cdot \text{log}(x) - x + C$ and so the definite integral evaluates to $e^x\cdot (x - 1) + 1$.

You may ask why?

Note that $\int(uv') = uv - \int(u'v)$ and set $u=\text{log}(x)$ and $v=1$.

Comment: This is a correct answer, but I don't think everyone will remember the indefinite integral of $\log$ by heart for the finals. ;)

Comment: @tomasz, making edit now.

Comment: Besides, this problem is obviously formulated with the substitution $t=e^u$ in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Since for every $u>0$ we have
$$
\int_1^u\ln t\,dt=t\ln t|_1^u-\int_1^u t(\ln t)'\,dt=u\ln u-\int_1^u\,dt=u\ln u-u+1,
$$
it follows that
$$
\int_1^{e^x}\ln t\,dt=xe^x-e^x+1=(x-1)e^x+1.
$$